# filtering R dataframe and show each variable once

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a huge dataframe that contains a column of gene's IDs. Each Gene ID appears in the column in a different number of times.
I want to extract from the dataframe a column that presents every Gene ID once, and at the same time I want to keep the data as a dataframe and not to change it to a list with factors.

example:
GeneID
589034
489034
589034
589034
48999
99449
99449

And i want my output to be:
GeneID
589034
489034
48999
99449

Comment: I provided an answer to your question using `unique`, but what do you mean by *at the same time I want to keep the data as a dataframe and not to change it to a list with factors*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unique` function for this:

```
dat = c('GeneID', '589034', '489034', '589034', '589034', '48999', '99449', '99449')
unique(dat)
[1] "GeneID" "589034" "489034" "48999"  "99449"
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!